# What happens when Windows runs out of handles?

Tags: windows

I see have an application which is using 40,000 handles. Could this be causing my system to become sluggish and unresponsive? What number of handles can Windows have before it becomes unstable?

Comment: Everything I'm seeing says the limit is 10K, but you're well beyond that. So, clearly something has changed.

Comment: "If you have to ask what the maximum is, you're probably doing it wrong" - TheDailyWTF

Comment: Haha, good quote, I'm a huge The Daily WTF fan myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft's Mark Russinovich provides lots of these kinds of tests on his blog.

See [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles)

Comment: From the article "Any process that has more than a ten thousand handles open at any given point in time is likely either poorly designed or has a handle leak" And I have to agree.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this could easily be causing your system to become sluggish and unresponsive. Is it a homegrown application or commercial?

1. Homegrown : fix the handle leak. Is something forgetting to close a file or TCP connection?
2. Commercial : open a bug report and get that fixed.

For either, in the meantime, how long does it take for that many open handles to build up? Try restarting the process on an interval that won't affect your production environment, if you can.